# Loop Formula Across Columns and Down Rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, formula

I'd like to loop a formula across columns and have it stop when it gets to the last column that I have defined, while also looping the formula down rows to the last row that I have defined in the respective columns. I think I have a rough idea of how some things should be defined but not a good idea of the most efficient loop to use or how the formula should be formatted. It should be noted that, in the 12th line of code, the starting row is variable. I’m open to using R1C1 notation if necessary to reformat the formula but I do not understand it very well.

```
Sub LoopAcrossColsRows()
Dim C as Integer
Dim R as Integer
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim lr As Long
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow  = Cells(Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).Row
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For C = 2 To Last Col
     For R = lr + 2 To LastRow
          Cells(C, R) = “SUMPRODUCT(--(C$6:C$7>=$A20),--(C$6:C$7<=($A20+30))*C$4)”
     Next R
Next C
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why looping in this case ?

```
Range(cells(2,3),cells(lr,lc)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1])"
```

should do the trick, much faster !

Answer (score 1):

To whoever comes across this thread, this is how to loop a simple formula using R1C1 notation across columns and rows.

```
Sub LoopAcrossColsRows()
    Dim c As Long, lc As Long, r As Long, lr As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        lc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For c = 3 To lc
            For r = 2 To lr
            .Cells(r, c).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1])"
            Next r
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```